# Quickest web framework / tool for an online log of data?

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, webforms

I have a client that is in need of an online log for keeping track of inventory of chemicals.

They need to be able to add chemicals and various attributes to the chemicals, then log when they use a certain amount & be able to log when they add amounts to their inventory.

Then they need reports of current inventory / last X days of activity, and activity of a specific chemical with sorting, etc.

I looked at Google forms with a spreadsheet backend, but it doesn't seem to fit my needs (I want some customization of the form depending on the chemical, be able to easily add / remove chemicals)

The data seems too simple to build from the ground up.  Any simple frameworks / product out there I should look at?  I'm platform agnostic (.NET / PHP / etc), my priority is that my time as the developer is reduced (I've coded in each platform).

Comment: try googling "inventory management software" or "inventory management saas" or "online inventory management"

Comment: thanks for the advice - I'm getting closer to a solution.  http://www.clearlyinventory.com/ - I wish I could use their software and customize it a bit for my client.  Any frameworks / project out there that I can modify?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/). It's a PHP UI framework and focused on development simplicity and quick-start.

Comment: I was asked to mention that I'm a contributor for this framework.

Comment: It's not a bad option, but I'd really prefer a framework or existing project that specifically does inventory or spreadsheet like tracking out of the box.  I may be looking for something that doesn't exist, in that case a web framework like this may be my only option

Comment: I know of a online project doing the inventory: http://www.scrazzl.com/ but from your description it sounded pretty simple - something which can be done with just a definition of a model and $page->add('CRUD')->setModel('Chemical'); Probably some additional fields depending on the chemical, and inheritance of class-based models is an ideal tool for that.